# Basic Paint App. Painting

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Basic Paint App where a circle moves around in a canvas. As the circles moves around in the canvas , what ever that circle is it should paint that area.

I get the position of the cursor(blue circle) to helper determine the path I should fill. By the end I will move the blue cursor until I fill the orange.

Is there anyway which will allow me to do this given the ios API?
I though about manipulating an ImageSkNode path. Or is there some canvas Object I can use?

[image]

```
func updateCanvas(players : [PlayerNode]){
    let copyPath = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(self.path) //get the last frame path
    for player in players{
        if self.intersectsNode(player){
          let posistion = player.position

          //CGPathAddEllipseInRect(copyPath, nil, CGRectMake(position.x, posistion.y, 50 , 50))

        }
    }

    self.path = copyPath

}
```